# parse.com 2 "doesNotMatchKey" in one query

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

is it possible to add 2 "doesNotMatchKey" in one query? im trying not to show "offers" that are saved & not to show offers that are deleted

```
// get query for all deleted offers
PFQuery *innerQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:P_CLASS_DELETED_OFFERS];
[innerQuery whereKey:P_DELETED_OFFER_USER_30X01 equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

// get query for all saved offers
PFQuery *innerSavedOfferQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:P_CLASS_SAVED_OFFER];
[innerSavedOfferQuery whereKey:P_SAVED_OFFER_USER_29X01 equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

//main query
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:P_CLASS_OFFER];
**[query whereKey:P_OBJECT_ID_CCX98 doesNotMatchKey:P_SAVED_OFFER_OFFER_STRING_ID_29X03       inQuery:innerSavedOfferQuery];
[query whereKey:P_OBJECT_ID_CCX98 doesNotMatchKey:P_DELETED_OFFER_OFFER_STRING_ID_30X03 inQuery:innerQuery];**
[query whereKey:P_OFFER_ITEM_20X02 containedIn:[NSArray arrayWithArray:[DataManager sharedInstance].myWantitArray]];
[query orderByAscending:P_OFFER_ITEM_20X02];
[query includeKey:P_OFFER_ITEM_20X02];
[query includeKey:P_OFFER_USER_20X01];

return query;
```

i insert this to the PFQueryTableController and get results that matches the main query without the second "doesNotMatchKey:" method, in this case - [query whereKey:P_OBJECT_ID_CCX98 doesNotMatchKey:P_DELETED_OFFER_OFFER_STRING_ID_30X03 inQuery:innerQuery]; is ignored.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is the [whereKey:notContainedIn:](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey%3anotContainedIn%3a) method. This lets you provide an array of keys you want to check against.

Comment: thanks, but for this method i need to have the array which i don't. i don't want to do it with 2 calls to parse - 1. call for the array 2.  'whereKey:notContainedIn:' method. its too slow.

Comment: @user3191110 Couldn't you create an array for the two keys you currently use with `whereKey:doesNotMatchKey:`, then you could use a single call using the method I suggested

Comment: how? i think i will have to use 2 **whereKey:doesNotMatchKey:** in that query for me to get them in to 1 array. don't i?

Comment: Ah sorry, I see your issue now. I didn't realise you were doing `whereKey:doesNotMatchKey:inQuery:`. There is support for OR queries, but you're using two different classes/tables for "Saved Offer" vs "Deleted Offer", so I doubt you can combine them. It sounds like your data structures are in conflict with your use cases :(